# IPtables not blocking wifi traffic on Raspberry Pi Access Point

Tags: wireless-networking, firewall, iptables, raspberry-pi, wireless-access-point

I have an rPi running as a wireless AP for my IoT devices. I'd like to set up a firewall rule to prevent suspicious traffic (why would the camera need access to SSH?). The rPi is connected to my router via an ethernet cable and I'm connecting to the rPi wifi with my phone to test the connection. The rPi is using an external antenna (wlan1).

So far I've tried

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DROP
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -o wlan1 -j DROP
```

I've also tried to block all internal traffic, but no dice

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan1 -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j DROP
```

The output of `iptables -L -v`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DROP       all  --  wlan1  any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Testing with vnstat I can see that there's traffic on wlan1

```
wlan1  /  traffic statistics

                           rx         |       tx
--------------------------------------+------------------
  bytes                      255 KiB  |        6.13 MiB
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max             165 kbit/s  |     5.06 Mbit/s
      average           22.70 kbit/s  |   558.99 kbit/s
          min               0 kbit/s  |        3 kbit/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  packets                       3392  |            4858
--------------------------------------+------------------
          max                255 p/s  |         455 p/s
      average                 36 p/s  |          52 p/s
          min                  0 p/s  |           1 p/s
--------------------------------------+------------------
  time                  1.53 minutes
```

And here's my htapd config:

```
# Bridge mode
bridge=br0

# Networking interface
interface=wlan1

# WiFi configuration
ssid=superdupernetwork
channel=1
hw_mode=g
country_code=US
ieee80211n=1
ieee80211d=1
wmm_enabled=1

# WiFi security
auth_algs=1
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_passphrase=superduperpass
```

I've ran Suricata over wlan1 and it detect traffic just fine, and also running `iptables -P INPUT DROP` kills my SSH connection, so something must be working. Thanks.

EDIT: The problem was caused by my bridge configuration. As can be seen in the `iptables -L -v` output, no packets were actually being forwarded. Removing the bridge mode from my `hostapd.conf` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have a rule to drop traffic to port 443, since you mention SSH. SSH uses port 22 by default. Basically it is superfluous in light of the second rule.

Use of `iptables -A FORWARD` is unclear, perhaps post your `/etc/network/interfaces` file (adding it to the initial post) ?

And even if you block traffic on the wifi interface the PI could still send traffic through the wired network (presumably eth0). You can use traceroute/tracepath to find out which interface is used for sending packets to a given IP address. I am wondering what are your criteria for deciding what is suspicious traffic ?

Probably a better approach would be to open only the ports that are needed, in and out, and also restrict the range of IP addresses that the PI is allowed to connect to.

Comment: 443 was used as an example, and for testing purposes. 
As I am not hosting the entirety of the internet on my rasPi, I have to use ```iptables -A FORWARD``` to forward the requests to my main router. The problem was caused by a misconfiguration in my bridge network, br0. Removing the bridge fixed it.